# Codeceptjs: Allure report doesnot show all steps in "Test body" section

Tags: allure, codeceptjs

I am trying to generate an allure report for my suite. I am getting the report but the report does not display all the steps in the Test body section. It only displays a screenshot of the failed test and if the test case passed it does not display anything.

here is my config I added

```
plugins:{
  allure:{
    enabled:true,
  },

  uniqueScreenshotNames:true,
  retryFailedStep:{
    enabled:true,
    retries:2,
  },
},
```

Screenshot of passed and failed test:

[image]

Screenshot of passed case

[image]

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's bug in 1.4.5 version.

Bug fix has been merged already.
https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/pull/1326

Next release will be work properly.
Change version to previous as Ernest Miles answered, if you need it, or wait for next release.

**UPD**
1.4.6 was released. Try it.

Comment: Yes, I tried 1.4.6 but there is another bug Now. have a look:

https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/1339

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same issue when bumped to version 1.4.5. Was using 1.4.1 before that. Went to 1.4.4 and it works as intended.